# Check which view sends gestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

This is what I want to do

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (touch.view != self.myView) {
        NSLog(@"we went with no");
        //don't let anything that's not myView fire the gesture recognizer
        return NO;
    }
    NSLog(@"we went with yes");
    return YES;
}
```

The problem is the code always chooses the path of `"we went with no"` no matter where I actually tap. How do I fix my if check?

Comment: `touch.view` is the view the touch originated in, which may not be the current view. Considering that, could `touch.view` be returning a subview of `self.myView`? Have you tried inspecting what `touch.view` is returning? If it is a subview, try something like `isDescendantOfView:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're finding that your gesture recognizer action is firing when you're tapping outside of a specific view, you should double-check that you added the gesture recognizer correctly.

```
[self.myView addGestureRecognizer:[[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:)]];
```

If you still experience incorrect action fires, you could check the touch location.

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.myView.bounds, [gesture locationInView:self.myView]))
```